# What are the standard values in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I was going through by CSS file and found alot of "height:auto;", and I was kinda, hey ... wait a minute, do I really have to state height as auto? Is this already set as default?

```
height:auto;
```

If yes, is there a complete list of all default values in html5?

Comment: Please refer to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701235/is-there-a-list-of-default-values-of-css-properties-so-i-can-make-an-exclusio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're searching for ? :)

```
; Sources:
;     http://reference.sitepoint.com/css
;     http://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS

animation                  = "none"
animation-delay            = "0"
animation-direction        = "normal"
animation-duration         = "0"
animation-fill-mode        = "none"
animation-iteration-count  = "1"
animation-name             = "none"
animation-play-state       = "running"
animation-timing-function  = "ease"
backface-visibility        = "visible"
background                 = "0"
background-attachment      = "scroll"
background-clip            = "border-box"
background-color           = "transparent"
background-image           = "none"
background-origin          = "padding-box"
background-position        = "0 0"
background-position-x      = "0"
background-position-y      = "0"
background-repeat          = "repeat"
background-size            = "auto auto"
border                     = "0"
border-style               = "none"
border-width               = "medium"
border-color               = "inherit"
border-bottom              = "0"
border-bottom-color        = "inherit"
border-bottom-left-radius  = "0"
border-bottom-right-radius = "0"
border-bottom-style        = "none"
border-bottom-width        = "medium"
border-collapse            = "separate"
border-image               = "none"
border-left                = "0"
border-left-color          = "inherit"
border-left-style          = "none"
border-left-width          = "medium"
border-radius              = "0"
border-right               = "0"
border-right-color         = "inherit"
border-right-style         = "none"
border-right-width         = "medium"
border-spacing             = "0"
border-top                 = "0"
border-top-color           = "inherit"
border-top-left-radius     = "0"
border-top-right-radius    = "0"
border-top-style           = "none"
border-top-width           = "medium"
bottom                     = "auto"
box-shadow                 = "none"
box-sizing                 = "content-box"
caption-side               = "top"
clear                      = "none"
clip                       = "auto"
color                      = "inherit"
columns                    = "auto"
column-count               = "auto"
column-fill                = "balance"
column-gap                 = "normal"
column-rule                = "medium none currentColor"
column-rule-color          = "currentColor"
column-rule-style          = "none"
column-rule-width          = "none"
column-span                = "1"
column-width               = "auto"
content                    = "normal"
counter-increment          = "none"
counter-reset              = "none"
cursor                     = "auto"
direction                  = "ltr"
display                    = "inline"
empty-cells                = "show"
float                      = "none"
font                       = "normal"
font-family                = "inherit"
font-size                  = "medium"
font-style                 = "normal"
font-variant               = "normal"
font-weight                = "normal"
height                     = "auto"
hyphens                    = "none"
left                       = "auto"
letter-spacing             = "normal"
line-height                = "normal"
list-style                 = "none"
list-style-image           = "none"
list-style-position        = "outside"
list-style-type            = "disc"
margin                     = "0"
margin-bottom              = "0"
margin-left                = "0"
margin-right               = "0"
margin-top                 = "0"
max-height                 = "none"
max-width                  = "none"
min-height                 = "0"
min-width                  = "0"
opacity                    = "1"
orphans                    = "0"
outline                    = "0"
outline-color              = "invert"
outline-style              = "none"
outline-width              = "medium"
overflow                   = "visible"
overflow-x                 = "visible"
overflow-y                 = "visible"
padding                    = "0"
padding-bottom             = "0"
padding-left               = "0"
padding-right              = "0"
padding-top                = "0"
page-break-after           = "auto"
page-break-before          = "auto"
page-break-inside          = "auto"
perspective                = "none"
perspective-origin         = "50% 50%"
position                   = "static"
; May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr)
quotes                     = "'\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019'"
right                      = "auto"
tab-size                   = "8"
table-layout               = "auto"
text-align                 = "inherit"
text-align-last            = "auto"
text-decoration            = "none"
text-decoration-color      = "inherit"
text-decoration-line       = "none"
text-decoration-style      = "solid"
text-indent                = "0"
text-shadow                = "none"
text-transform             = "none"
top                        = "auto"
transform                  = "none"
transform-style            = "flat"
transition                 = "none"
transition-delay           = "0s"
transition-duration        = "0s"
transition-property        = "none"
transition-timing-function = "ease"
unicode-bidi               = "normal"
vertical-align             = "baseline"
visibility                 = "visible"
white-space                = "normal"
widows                     = "0"
width                      = "auto"
word-spacing               = "normal"
z-index                    = "auto"
```

Comment: Neither of the resources cited is authoritative, and they describe initial values rather than default values.

Answer (score 2):

You have [this for Firefox](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/style/html.css)

[And this for Chrome](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

[W3C also have a recommended style set for HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

You may want to [look here for a list of default styles](http://www.iecss.com/) for IE

YOu can always use debug tools like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to inspect elements to ascertain their inherited, provided and computed styles. Or look to using a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) so you know you're dealing with all browsers on a level playing field.

I'd love to include the rules as part of this post but unfortunately they exceed the 30k character limit for an SO answer.